WPF Datagrid - Custom Column Layout
I'm looking to create a custom layout for a datagrid column. I want to stack some columns like you can with Infragistics (one above another), but I want to do it myself. Is this possible? I've searched the internet and can't find anything.
I've tried many tutorials and can't find anything about stacking columns in a datagrid. I've searched the internet and can't find anything. Is it possible to stack columns in a datagrid?
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <!-- Style pour les en-têtes groupés -->
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <!-- Définir les colonnes du DataGrid -->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- Colonne 1 -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" />

            <!-- Colonne 2 avec en-tête groupé -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Primary Name" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Secondary Name" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrimaryName}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondaryName}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!-- Colonne 3 -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>

`
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadDataGrid();
    }

    private void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        // Données
        var data = new List<MyData>
        {
            new MyData { Id = 1, PrimaryName = "John", SecondaryName = "Doe", Age = 25 },
            new MyData { Id = 2, PrimaryName = "Jane", SecondaryName = "Doe", Age = 30 },
            new MyData { Id = 3, PrimaryName = "Sam", SecondaryName = "Smith", Age = 35 }
        };

        // Lier les données
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
    }
}

`
public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryName { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


Your explanations are completely unclear. Clarify your question. Provide some screenshots of the required result.

You're right, I added the example code that I worked on.
Also, I tried to make the same as Infragistics, so stacked vertically instead of horizontally ... Thanks

A "StackPanel" can be oriented horizontally or vertically via its "Orientation" property. You should specify Orientation=Vertical in your XAML in this case, because it is not obvious which "default" value it might be using (and the docs are not always clear).
